# Limit number of outgoing messages in postfix

Tags: postfix

Is there some good way to limit outbound mail in postfix? I want to limit number of sent messages by domain per some time interval.

Imaginary example:

I have email accounts in 3 different domains: tld1, tld2 and tld3. It is not relevant how many accounts in what domain.

- All accounts in tld1 can send at most 20 messages per hour.
- All accounts in tld2 can send at most 10 messages per hour.
- All accounts in tld3 can send at most 25 messages per hour.

Can this be done? And how?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want [policyd](http://www.policyd.org/tiki-index.php) -- it appears to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I found policyd. But, i am not really expert in those thing. I can't figure out hoe to configure it.
I understand that I can create different policies (http://www.policyd.org/tiki-index.php?page=Policies%20%26%20Groups&structure=Documentation) but, where can I do this? Is there some configuration file?

Comment: I've never used it, Google told me all about it.  Based on 30 seconds with the docs, though, it looks like you want the Quota module -- there's an example to do pretty much exactly what you want right there.