# Postfix count relayed messages per user

Tags: linux, postfix, quota

I would like to know if it's possible to count the outgoing (relayed) messages on a per user basis in postfix.

I'm managing a small commercial SMTP relay and decided that it would be nice to have a detailed daily report on how much mail a single user have sent (and eventually enforce some limits) possibly in realtime.

I've looked almost everywhere and started to think that writing my own milter would be the way to go...

Are you aware of anything that already exists for postfix that can count and report relayed mail for authenticated users (a script, milter or whatever)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit number of outgoing messages in postfix](http://serverfault.com/questions/85957/limit-number-of-outgoing-messages-in-postfix)

Comment: Well it's not exactly a duplicate of that question, but indeed the answer solves my problem too! Thanks mailq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mailq I found the solution, as womble pointed out on the previous question, [policyd](http://www.policyd.org/) is the answer. From the 2.1x version (unstable branch) there is an accounting module which can [enforce limits](http://wiki.policyd.org/accounting).